# Making WinEdt QuickGuide.tex work with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, winedt

Can the WinEdt QuickGuide.tex be modified to work with XeLaTeX?

Comment: Ask the inventors of WinEdt and document writers if you got the permission to change it ;-) Why should it be modified at all? What's wrong with `pdflatex` compilation? Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I wanted to use that template in a new document for a solutions manual but I wanted to use matlab-prettiefer using the Consolas font also.

Comment: There is a clear statement: `\author{\textsc{Aleksander Simonič}\\ \small{\copyright~1993--2015}}`  in the QuickGuide.tex` . Ask Aleksander for permission to use the 'template'

Comment: Note that, in contrast, `xrcs.sty` explicitly says that no rights are reserved and that it is fine to use and modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested. There are only two lines to modify, in the  `%non-pdf branch`:

- line 272, among the options of `hyperref`, replace `hypertex` with `xetex`;
- line 281 comment (or delete) the `kerning` option  for `microtype`:

[image]

Furthermore, you must adapt the font settings: loading `inputenc` is pointless, since XeLaTeX supposes the source-code is `UTF8`encoded, and loading `fontenc` is useful only if you want also to use some `non-.otf` or `non-.ttf` fonts, that require the traditional LaTeX handling (.fd, .tfm  and .vf files, &c.):

[image]

Finally you must load `fontspec` to use Opentype or Truetype fonts:

[image]

Comment: Note that it is not clear that this is legal given the discussion in the comments. Doesn't it also use `inputenc`, `fix-cm`, `fontenc` etc.? (I deleted the copy I downloaded in light of the comments so may be misremembering.)

Comment: Perhaps. It was just for testing. Now, if it finally comes out to be legal, the O.P. will know it's easy.

Comment: One must certainly remove inputenc. One should add fontspec. One should adapt the font setup.

Comment: @Ulrike Fisher: You're right. I only showed the minimal changes in order  to compile with XeLaTeX. I've added these details.

Comment: Alex's reply was that it is in "public domain".  Also @Bernard, after doing your changes, it compiles with xelatex now, but I see red boxes around the hyperlinks now in the generated pdf file.  Is this just a PDF issue or something related to the modifed code?

Comment: That is because Alex probably didn't fully test the `nonpdfbranch` in the code. Just add these lines between lines 273 and 274 (just after `,breaklinks%`): 
               `,colorlinks%
               ,linkcolor={Navy}%`